# Does a correct channel exists to send a JWT?

Tags: php, ajax, jwt

Does exists a correct channel to send a JWT from a client to a server (Web development with PHP) ?
Is it necessary to send all data over the HTTP Header, Authentication over the HTTP Authentication Hander? Or is it also best practice to send the JWT over GET, POST or an AJAX too? Or is it every time dependent on the application?

In my opinion shouldn't be a problem to use other channel. Because the JWT contain the data, is digitally signed and on the server I can verify this values.

Comment: Generally, unless you have a good reason not to, use the Authorization http header or a similar header. If you have it in the http header there is no reason to add it to the body of a POST.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the [RFC 7519 - JSON Web Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519), usually solve doubts

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is a compact claims representation format intended for space constrained environments such as **HTTP Authorization headers and URI query parameters**.

There is no a preferred way. You can use the default Authorization header, typically using the 'Bearer' schema

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

But you can also an use your own header, send it with POST, GET, use forms or ajax with a REST api. Really, if you search a bit, there are a lot of different ways.

Take a look to this excellent introduction to JWT at https://jwt.io/introduction/ which explain some themes like this